# Is "close them both" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

> Closing either the UI editor or `settings.json` should close them both.

I know that "close them all" is correct but is "close them both" also correct?

I googled "close them both" and found it's not used much.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @KateBunting Would not some people say that 'all' is incorrect, or at least awkward, for fewer than three things?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I wasn't intending to suggest that _all_ would be correct in this context. I assumed that the OP was just using it as a parallel construction.